# http-on-modify-request observer doesn't seem to be ready at firefox startup

Tags: firefox-addon

For SSO purpose, I have a firefox add-on who add additional headers into each request.

Everything works fine but for "link" like in outlook or third part applications.

After a click, the link will load the page but randomly the add-on seems to be loaded after the first request.

Could it be possible to ensure my observer is clearly loaded before the first request?

```
var observers = {
    'http-on-modify-request': {
        observe: function(aSubject, aTopic, aData) {
                //some code here            

        },
        reg: function() {
            Services.obs.addObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request', false);
        },
        unreg: function() {
            Services.obs.removeObserver(observers['http-on-modify-request'], 'http-on-modify-request');
        }
    }
};

for (var o in observers) {
    console.log("register observers "+o);
    observers[o].reg();
}
```

Comment: This is a good question. It makes sense that the observer gets addon when your addon is started up, I didn't think that addon startup happens after tabs start to load. I'm eager to see solution for this as well.

Comment: We need more code to begin to answer this question. Your issue is that the observer is not active prior to the first request. We need to see when/how this code is executed within your add-on. The code you have provided could tell us if the observer is going to work at all, not when it would be come active.

Comment: Makyen : the code is not more complicated than that (to isolate the bug). I can just add a "console.log" instead of "//some code here" and you will randomly not have the first request in the addon log file.